# Be it rich or be it poor

Tags: sentence

People should be treated equally be it rich or be it poor.

Is it a correct sentence. If yes what does it mean???

Comment: Can you give a link to the source? Context always helps

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct, I think; change to "be they rich or be they poor", or less dramatically, "be they rich or poor" - your choice.

Comment: Oh, and please never, ever use more than one question mark or exclamation mark unless it's in a message to a friend, perhaps.